Machine Learning classification algorithms for multi-level data
I'm working on a machine learning project, and my dataset contains variables about social, demographic and economic aspects of 218 countries, ranging from 1960 to 2022. The target variable is a binary variable (Yes or No) that represents if the country has had at least one attempt of coup d'etat in a specific year.
My question is: what are the best classification models for multi-level data?
From consulting different sources, I've wrote down these models (no particular order):

Random Forest
XGBoost
Logistic Classification
Decision Tree

Are they the wrong ones? Are there more models I'm not aware of?
If not, do you know any source I can use to implement these models in R?

Please note that this is not a programming question, we do not do recommendations of ML models in Stack Overflow.

I think that you are on the right track.
Based on the number of parameters that you have, I would suggest going with Random Forest of XGB.
(Logistic Regression assumes from my understanding linear relationship between your variables, so you might need to dig into data visualization first. Decision Tree is prone to overfitting, so with no more information on your dataset, I wouldn't suggest this).
Keep in mind that RF and XGB are computationally expensive, and require tuning (depth, regularization...). However, by following some tutorials and applying principles, you might be able to produce an accurate model using any of them.
They would allow you to grasp complex relationship within the data. However, they are also a bit less interpretable than LR and DT.
You might also consider another well used algorithm, Support Vector Machines (SVM), but I have no idea on how to use it in R
